# Whats the best way to simulate/animate mesh/cartoon hair in 2.9?

Tags: modeling, physics, eevee-render-engine

I plan on doing full-blown anime style animations and do to this I need something flexible, for flying, running, falling, underwater, space, etc, scenes, but I have to have full control. I'm thinking about using cloth physics to do this, but I'm not really sure nor how to go about it. Also, it has to be able to collide with the character and other stuff.

If it helps I'm using 2.9 and the eevee engine.

Comment: Cloth Physics is a solution, you can only give physics to a series of edges and these edges will guide bones that will deform the hair, you could also try the Wiggle Bones addon, but it seems a bit contradictory to say that you want full control on your hair (in that case use bones?) and that you are going to use physics

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear I just meant, like when hair gets wet, it gets heaver, or when your underwater your hair is more flowy. I just meant I can change the weight and flexibility, and so on.